# Skeleton equal height columns

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

Skeleton uses float:left and display:inline for all columns. I need to make my columns equal height but still maintain the float:left and display:inline so they behave as expected when browser window resizes. Any idea?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you want equal height but not *fixed* height columns?